# Python Output Gives Object Address Instead of Values

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of trouble with this assignment, here's my current code.

This is the Class for the employees on a separate python file.

```
class Employee:
    
    #Initializes the classes for the employee information
    def __init__(self, name, id_number, department, title):
        self.set_name = name
        self.set_id_number = id_number
        self.set_department = department
        self.set_title = title

    #Sets attributes to the information
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def set_id_number(self, id_number):
        self.id_number = id_number

    def set_department(self, department):
        self.department = department

    def set_title(self, title):
        self.title = title

    #Returns the information's attributes
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_id_number(self):
        return self.id_number

    def get_department(self):
        return self.department

    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name:' + self.name + \
               '\nID Number:' + self.id_number + \
               '\nDepartment:' + self.department + \
               '\nJob Title:' + self.title
```

Here is the main code that is supposed to print the information about the employees:

```
import employee

def main():

    #Creates the three instances of the employees
    emp1=employee.Employee("Susan Meyers", "47899", "Accounting", \
                           "Vice President")
    emp2=employee.Employee("Mark Jones", "39119", "IT", "Programmer")
    emp3=employee.Employee("Joy Rogers", "81774", "Manufacturing", \
                           "Engineer")

    #Prints information about the employees
    print("EMPLOYEE INFORMATION:")
    print("---------------------")
    print("Employee 1:")
    print(emp1, '\n')
    print("Employee 2:")
    print(emp2, '\n')
    print("Employee 3:")
    print(emp3, '\n')
    
main()
```

This is the output I get when I run the 2nd file on this post:

```
EMPLOYEE INFORMATION:
---------------------
Employee 1:
<employee.Employee object at 0x000002BE14A959D0> 

Employee 2:
<employee.Employee object at 0x000002BE14ABB0A0> 

Employee 3:
<employee.Employee object at 0x000002BE14B622B0>
```

Not sure why this is happening, but if anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean: `def __str__(self):`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Remember to condense your code down to a [mre] that replicates your problem with the minimum amount of code. It's not okay to dump all your code here and ask others to debug it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The string conversion function is `__str__`, not `_str_`. Adding a `_` before and after should fix your problem.

---

More feedback, while not related to the question:

- Use the following to call your `main()` instead. While not absolutely necessary, it is good practice. It prevents `main()` from being run if you use the `.py` file in an `import` statement.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- In the constructor of your class, the usage of the setter functions is incorrect. You need to call them instead of setting them.

Afterwards, it should work:
https://ideone.com/2mnd3g

Comment: I figured it out, because at the top of the 2nd file I put self.set_name = name, I didn't keep it consistent throughout the rest of the file, so after changing all of the self.(X) to self.set_(X), it worked.